# How do I use the input of one field in multiple places on a form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm very new to Django, so please forgive me if I'm using some of the terminology incorrectly.

In one of my templates, I'm trying to use a form that has multiple input fields. In this specific case, the value of the two fields will always be the same (userName and userID will always match if they are at this template) and I do not want to alter the form itself. For this reason, I want to customize the form in this template so that there is only one place for the user to provide input, and use that in both fields of the form so that the user doesn't need to type in their ID twice.

This is the code fragment I'm currently using:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label>ID:</label>
  <input type="text" name="userID" id="userID" placeholder="Type your ID number here.">
  <input type="hidden" name="userName" id="userName" value=userID>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

I know that the issue is with the "value=userID" bit, but I've been searching and I can't figure out how to use information from one input field in multiple places. How do I take the userID and submit it as the userName without requiring the user to input it twice?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, You can use the same value in the backend. You do not need to make a hidden field for that. Kindly update your question and show us the View and Form to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide the same input **two times** to use it in your back-end. You can use the same value in the back-end.

So let's say you have want the `userName` in your back-end to be same as `userID` value:

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userID = request.POST.get('userID')
        userName = userID
```

That was the basic idea, if you are using class based views with Django's forms, you should place this code in the `form_valid` method.